# Perl/Zapier integration via webhooks

Tags: json, perl, zapier

I'd like to set up integration with zapier.com/help/webhooks which I'm hoping will give me useful access to a lot of apps without integrating with each app's API.  I'm told I need to POST some JSON to Zapier and then parse the response.  Here's what I have but I'm getting: "Usage: $http->www_form_urlencode(DATAREF)".

```
my %data = (
            id  => "1234",
            first_name => "Name",
            email  => "email@example.com",
            phone  => "1234567890",
);
my $data = \%data;

my $http = HTTP::Tiny->new();
my $params = $http->www_form_urlencode( $data );
my $response = $http->post_form($url, $params);
```

Comment: This question is waaaaayyyy too broad.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question

Answer (score 0):

Posting is easily done with [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny).  There is a plethora of JSON parsers on CPAN. See, e.g. [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working like this:

```
use HTTP::Tiny;

my %data = (
        id  => "1234",
        first_name => "Name",
        email  => "email\@example.com",
        phone  => "1234567890",
);

my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->post_form('https://www.example.com', \%data);
```